# error: 'Point' does not name a type

Tags: ros, package.xml, include, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to utilize the geometry_msgs 'Point' type and receiving this error:

/home/viki/catkin_ws/src/ibvs/src/visual_servoing.cpp:42:1: error: ‘Point’ does not name a type
Point CENTER = Point(WIDTH/2, HEIGHT/2);
^

I'm assuming its something to do with my Cmakelists.txt or package.xml, as I've specified the include.

Cmakelists.txt: [http://imgur.com/a/CF2hb](https://imgur.com/a/CF2hb)

package.xml: [http://imgur.com/a/PTQzD](https://imgur.com/a/PTQzD)

visual_servoing.cpp: [http://imgur.com/a/N90cB](https://imgur.com/a/N90cB)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263665/error:-%27point%27-does-not-name-a-type/) by [Dominati](https://answers.ros.org/users/30727/dominati/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2017-06-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dominati](https://answers.ros.org/users/30727/dominati/) on 2017-06-11**:
I've also tried an alternate syntax, which still returns a similar error (see image link below).

[http://imgur.com/a/Uk4HQ](https://imgur.com/a/Uk4HQ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like there are a few problems here:

- The `Point` class is in the `geometry_msgs` namespace, so you should use the fully-namespaced class type: `geometry_msgs::Point`
- ROS message types (such as point) only have default constructors, so you have to construct the object before you can fill in its fields.
- You cannot have code outside of a function or class in C++ (as in your second try)

P.S. - for future questions please use the "preformatted text" button and paste your code and error messages directly into the question.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1